# Export variable from one file to another in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

I am currently working on a react-native based website and I am struggling to pass values from one file to another.
The value I am trying to import is 'Key':

```
class Encrypt extends Component {
encryptData = async() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:7000/Data')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      var pub1Key = data ;
      var Key=pub1Key["encryptedData"];
}
```

And use it like this

```
class Decrypt extends Component {
  deData(){
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({data: Key })
  };
```

I tried to use export option but it didn't work. 
These are two separate files. Encrypt.js and Decrypt.js.

Comment: you can't export like that, you'd need to manage global state using Context or redux etc,
or use this key in a parent Component and pass the setters,
one of the way is to set it globally to the window object like window.yourKey, but its not best practice

Comment: Hi @Avinash. I am a complete beginner to React-native and don't quite know how to use context here. The value of the 'Key' variable is being obtained after performing a few operations ie it is not pre-determined. Is there any way context can be used in this case?

Comment: If you are navigating from Encrypt component to Decrypt component than you can pass it through route params.

Comment: @SwatiBaleri Is this key `encryptedData` will be fetched from an external API source?

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this via any state manager. You can use Redux or Mobx or ReactContext for that.

However, if this is the token that is required for authentification or data that you want to access even after the page will be reloaded, you can simply store it in AsyncStorage.

So your code would look something like that.

```
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';

class Encrypt extends Component {
encryptData = async() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:7000/Data')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      //you can decrypt 'data' here
      return AsyncStorage.setItem('pub1Key', data);
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
      //handle any errors here
    })
}


class Decrypt extends Component {
  async getData(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
      try{
        const data = await AsyncStorage.setItem('pub1Key', data);
        //you can encrypt data here
        resolve(data);
      } catch(e){
        reject(e);
      }
    })
  };
```

The docs for that.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage.html

Comment: HI @SwatiBaleri , were you able to use the Async Storage to solve your problem?